# Mikvah during UK COVID-19 Lockdown

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah, dina-dmalchusa-dina

The UK is currently under a strict lockdown, prohibiting the leaving of one's home for any other than the following purposes:<sup>[gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/full-guidance-on-staying-at-home-and-away-from-others/full-guidance-on-staying-at-home-and-away-from-others#staying-at-home)</sup>

> - Shopping for basic necessities, for example food and medicine, which must be as infrequent as possible.
> - One form of exercise a day, for example a run, walk, or cycle - alone or with members of your household.
> - Any medical need, or to provide care or to help a vulnerable person.
> - Travelling to and from work, but only where this absolutely cannot be done from home.
>
> (…)
>
> In addition, the Government is stopping social events, including weddings, baptisms and other religious ceremonies.

**Have any rabbinical authorities given any advise regarding married women going to mikvah?**

Comment: Contacting the local mikvaot there will surely get someone better answers than asking here.

Comment: Maybe ask about Italy where there is enforced lockdown, Why should Mikva in UK be worst than going to do ones job (role), especially if a woman can get exercise by walking there.

Comment: I find it odd that 4 users have voted to close this as *asking for a practical ruling (p'sak halacha)* when I explicitly ask for references to statements by existing authorities, not for an ad-hoc ruling for myself.

Comment: I've asked a friend from Italy, and he said that women could get an appointment. I don't know how did they organise the rest with the state authorities.

Comment: I don't know about in the UK, but in the US there's been discussion on whether there is some way to tovel oneself outside of a mikvah, since some have had to close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://www.theus.org.uk/sites/default/files/Coronavirus%20-%20Community%20and%20Rabbinic%20Issues%20-%2025.3.2020_0.pdf) is the guidance issued by the United Synagogue.

> The observance of *Taharat Hamishpacha* (the laws of family purity) is a fundamental mitzvah. Mikvaot remain open for women. Best-practice guidelines on hygiene and social distancing are in place at local Mikvaot in North London. As each mikvah operates independently, women should contact their mikvah for detailed information. Men who have the tradition to go to the mikvah should refrain from doing so at this time.

Comment: If you add a link, you get a checkmark.

Comment: Tracked down the link for you. You should know they put out a [newer announcement](https://www.theus.org.uk/sites/default/files/Coronavirus%20-%20Community%20and%20Rabbinic%20Issues%20-%2020.3.2020.pdf) which simply reads: "Mikvaot remain open and detailed guidance has been shared with mikvah attendants. Women are advised to contact the mikvah for more information. Men who have the tradition to go to mikvah should refrain from doing so at this time."